# Let $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$. Does $\varepsilon \in \Sigma^*$?

Tags: formal-languages

I know it's really basic question but here it is:

Does the null word $\varepsilon$ belongs to the set of all words of an alphabet $\Sigma$?

For example,
Let $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$. Does $\varepsilon \in \Sigma^*$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Yes, by definition of the Kleene closure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Definition_and_notation)

Comment: Another way of thinking about it: well, every letter of the null word certainly lies in $\{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See definition for [Kleene Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).  The short answer to your question is 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

Usually. The zero, a neutral with respect to addition (concatenation) is a comfortable thing to have. This is the reason why we want it to be there.